# extern "C" for member static callback function

Tags: c++, c, callback, language-lawyer, extern

I want to provide a callback function for code written in Haskell (GHC). It uses GCC C-compiler-like function types to export/import functionality and interoperate at runtime with my code.

I have to provide a callback function, which in fact accept `this` pointer to the class and just call its method:

```
struct C
{
    int f(int i) { ; }
    static int f_callback(void * self, int i)
    {
        static_cast< C * >(self)->f(i);
    }
};
```

Logically `f_callback` is a part of class `C`, so I placed it into the corresponding namespace scope.

But I worry about should I use `extern "C"` language specification (calling convention is matters here, not name mangling)? It is possible to declare and define `extern "C"` function in plain namespace, there are a couple of special rules for `extern "C"` functions defined with the same name in different namespaces, but [there is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) no distinction between namespace of class scope and simple namespace one.

Is it possible to define `static extern "C"` function into class scope?

Comment: No, it's not possible IIRC. But you shouldn't have to worry that C and C++ use a different ABI or stack framing.

Comment: @user0042 Would be `static __cdecl` more safe then nothing?

Comment: It's a non portable annotation, but yes you can use that.

Comment: You can write a wrapper outside to call this static function and mark that with`extern "C"`

Comment: @user0042 I stick GCC/llvm infrastructure/environment, so I think I can't violate ABI accidentally.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya It is implied, but from design point of view it is more proper to declare/define mentioned callback into corresponding class namespace scope.

Comment: On Windows you could write module definition file so function will be exported without name mangling even if it a static class member.

Comment: @user0042 Turns out, that `[[gnu::cdecl]]` is the default and `-Wattributes` tell me, that it is ignored. So no need to specify something special for callback. You are right.

Comment: @VTT it is not just about name mangling. What if the inner call throws an exception?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Typically C callback functions should be marked with `noexcept` or manually capture exceptions and convert them to the error reporting form appropriate to the calling code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The external callback is by design not linked to a specific class.

Making it a static class member is perhaps nice according to the internals of your code, but it misrepresents the reality.

I'd therefore advise to make it an independent extern "C" function. This avoids misunderstanding and highlights assumptions (for example that self is assumed to be a C but could in reality be something else).  If f() is public, all this will be very clean. If it would be private, you'd need to make your callback a friend and this tight coupling would be again highlighted.

The wrapper alternative would just add a redundant middleman to come to the same result.